# "Far from" Vs "A long way"

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

I have no idea if grammatically there is any rule which makes a distinction between using "far from" and "a long way" in positive and negative sentences! Please have a look on my examples below and let me know if all the sentences sound correct. If not, then please let me know how should I "far from" and "a long way from" correctly:

> - 1.1- The bus station is **far from here**.
> - 1.2- The bus station is **a long way from here**.
> - 2.1- The bus station is "not" **far from here**.
> - 2.2- The bus station is "not" **a long way from here**.

To me, they all sound correct.

Comment: "a long way from" is more colloquial/casual/spoken and "far from" is slightly more formal. But otherwise, all fine.

Answer (score 0):

They all seem fine.  For 1.1, I might be more likely to say "the bus station is quite far from here" or "pretty far" or "very far".  2.2 seems a little unusual, but correct.  I would be more likely to say 2.1 than 2.2.  2.2 you could say if contradicting someone who just said 1.2.

Answer (score -2):

The bus station can be not far from here, just on the other side of the river, but it can be a long way from here, since the closest bridge is 2 kilometers away.